# prove $\frac{|\arcsin(\sin(\pi x))|}{\pi} = |x - \operatorname{round}(x)|$ for all real x

Tags: trigonometry

I have looked at this on my graphing calculator but I want a mathematical proof. can somebody please give me mathematical proof or a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's study the problem of determining $\arcsin\sin t$. There are two cases ($k$ denotes an integer):

1. if $-\pi/2+2k\pi\le t\le \pi/2+2k\pi$, then $t-2k\pi\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ and therefore $\arcsin\sin t=t-2k\pi$;
2. if $\pi/2+2k\pi\le t\le 3\pi/2+2k\pi$, then $-\pi/2+2k\pi\le t-\pi\le \pi/2+2k\pi$ and we're in the same case as before, so $\arcsin\sin t=t-\pi-2k\pi$.

For $t=\pi x$, the conditions read

1. if $-1/2+2k\le x\le 1/2+2k$, then $\dfrac{\arcsin\sin(\pi x)}{\pi}=x-2k$
2. if $1/2+2k\le x\le 3/2+2k$, then $\dfrac{\arcsin\sin(\pi x)}{\pi}=x-2k-1$

Set $y=x+1/2$. Then we're in case 1 when $2k\le y\le 2k+1$, in case 2 when $1+2k\le y\le 2k+2$. We can remove the upper extreme in both cases, because the final value would be the same for numbers belonging to both classes of intervals.

Therefore we can say that
$$
\frac{\arcsin\sin(\pi x)}{\pi}=x-\left\lfloor x+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor
$$
Now you should be able to conclude.

Comment: can you please conclude for me I am not able to solve that myself

Comment: @datboi For $x>0$, $\lfloor x+1/2\rfloor$ is what you call $\operatorname{round}(x)$: can you prove that? Then think to what happens when $x<0$, using that $\arcsin(-t)=-\arcsin t$.

Comment: so what you are saying is that this is true if x>0 ???

Comment: @datboi No; when $x<0$ you have to do some work more.

Comment: so what is the answer if x<0 ???

Answer (score 0):

**Solution of the injective part of the $sin(x)$**

Notice that the $\arcsin(\sin(\pi(x))) = \pi x$ exactly when $\frac{-\pi}{2} < \pi x <\frac{\pi}{2} \implies -\frac{1}{2} < x < \frac{1}{2}$ . Maybe you would expect that $\arcsin(\sin(\pi(x))) = \pi x$ for all $x$, but since the $\sin$ function lacks the property of injectivity, the identity does not hold everyhere. Now, the problem simplies to

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{|\pi x|}{\pi} = |x| = |x-\textrm{round}(x)| \quad \textrm{for} \quad -\frac{1}{2} < x < \frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}
since $|x| < \frac{1}{2}$, we have that round$(x) = 0$. Hence, the problem simplifies to
\begin{equation}
|x| = |x|, \quad \textrm{for} \quad -\frac{1}{2} < x < \frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}
Hence, $x$ is a solution as long as it satisfies $-\frac{1}{2} < x < \frac{1}{2}$. For all other $x$, I do not think an algebraic proof is easy to make.

Comment: thank you for the proof for -1/2<x<1/2

Comment: I wouldn't spent too much effort into finding a solution for other $x$, as I think this algebraically really hard to solve. However, I don't mind getting suprised, maybe there is an elegant way to rewrite the equation :)

Comment: Also, maybe you can take the plot again, and check visually whether an answer for other $x$ exists. If not so, you could write a hypothesis that there are no other solutions, as this is easier to check (for instance, that their difference is always positive so they dont intersect etc.) Could you maybe post the plot? I think we will be able to solve it afterwards :)

Comment: here is the link to a graph https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oianma9fxq